# Date Functions Conversions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way using TSQL to convert an integer to year, month and days

for e.g. 365 converts to 1year 0 months and 0 days
366 converts to 1year 0 months and 1 day

20 converts to 0 year 0 months and 20 days
200 converts to 0 year 13 months and 9 days 
408 converts to 1 year 3 months and 7 days .. etc

Comment: is this actually sql-server-2008? the exact version is important

Comment: Something like: select cast(<Your_Integer> as datetime)

Comment: I believe, there is no in-built function in sql-server but you can find it out with mathematical computation.

Comment: Hi,Yes its in Sql Server 2008R2

Comment: By what logic does “408 convert to 1 year 3 months and 7 days”? The answer isn’t going to be a constant as not all months (or years) are the same length. And this isn’t going to be the right answer ever as it is only 43 days over a normal year.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any inbuilt way in SQL Server 2008, but the following logic will give you all the pieces you need to concatenate the items together:

```
select
     n
   , year(dateadd(day,n,0))-1900 y
   , month(dateadd(day,n,0))-1 m
   , day(dateadd(day,n,0))-1 d
from (
    select 365 n union all
    select 366 n union all
    select 20 n union all
    select 200 n union all
    select 408 n
    ) d

| n     | y | m | d  |
|-------|---|---|----|
| 365   | 1 | 0 |  0 |
| 366   | 1 | 0 |  1 |
|  20   | 0 | 0 | 20 |
| 200   | 0 | 6 | 19 |
| 408   | 1 | 1 | 12 |
```

Note that zero used in in the DATEDADD function is the date 1900-01-01, hence 1900 is deducted from the year calculation.

*Thanks to Martin Smith for correcting my assumption about the leap year.*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the Comments but really dont want to HardCode it Is any any other way to achieve this.??

Comment: Hardcode?... you don't like 4 constants?(they really  do not change).  Accurate date unit arithmetic isnt trivial and the inbuilt dateadd function gives you quick accurate results.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks, I stand corrected which should allow use of zero in dateadd, i will try it later.

Comment: This answer has changed to use "the zero date" (1900-01-01) which also removes a string constant, zero is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try without using any functions just by dividing `integer` values if we consider all `months` are 30 `days`:

```
DECLARE @days INT;
SET @days = 365;

SELECT [Years] = @days / 365,
       [Months] = (@days % 365) / 30,
       [Days] = (@days % 365) % 30;
```

@days = 365

```
Years   Months  Days
1       0       0
```

@days = 20

```
Years   Months  Days
0       0       20
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh,Let me try and update you on this..Thanks for the Comments!!